# Pinit Button is not working in IE11 in magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, product-images, gallery-image

I have added `pinit save button` using following guide [Pinit Widget builder](https://developers.pinterest.com/tools/widget-builder/) in product detail page in gallery widget.

I have added `pinit.js` at the end of `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml`

It works in `Mozilla` and `Chrome` but it does not work in `IE11`. However it shows errors in `console` which are not concerned with pinit like

> Unable to get property 'dialog' of undefined or null reference : translate-inline.js (22,5) 
>   Unable to get property 'timepicker' of undefined or null reference : jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js (18,2)

I think `IE11` renders the `pinit.js` instantly or something else.

> Update 1: It is something related to `fotoroma gallery widget`. As I remove the gallery and replace it with the simple image it works fine.
>
> Errors in console.
>
> [image: errors in console]

Answer (score -1):

This issue generally happened in **Internet Explorer (IE)**  Because your Js file is not loaded.

Comment: It actully requests for the `pinit.js` and got `304(Not Modified)` status. I can see it in network tab of `IE` Developer tools.